# Jquery: get text from text node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of these divs and I want them to disappear if the sale price is $0.00

```
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
    <em>
         <strike class="RetailPriceValue">$79.99</strike> 
         $0.00
    </em>
    <span class="Rating Rating0">
        <img src="..." alt="" style="display: none" />
    </span>
</div>
```

So I wrote this jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(".ProductPriceRating em").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType != 1; 
    }).wrap("<span></span>");
    console.log($(".ProductPriceRating em span").text());
    if($(".ProductPriceRating span").text() == ' $0.00'){
            console.log('success');
        $('div.ProductPriceRating').hide();
        $('div.ProductActionAdd').hide();
    }
});
```

I wrapped a span tag around the text node to make it easier to access. Then I console log it and get " $0.00 $0.00 $0.00" (one " $0.00" for each of the elements on the page). But no success.

I just don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: So you're no longer trying to get text from a textnode, you've wrapped it in a span from the time you wrote the title of the question, and now you're trying to do something completely different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through every parent element:

From:

```
if($(".ProductPriceRating span").text() == ' $0.00'){
        console.log('success');
    $('div.ProductPriceRating').hide();
    $('div.ProductActionAdd').hide();
}
```

To:

```
$(".ProductPriceRating").each(function() { 
    if($(this).find('span').text() == ' $0.00'){
            console.log('success');
        $(this).hide();
        $('div.ProductActionAdd').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you only have

```
$(".ProductPriceRating span").text()
```

In your console.log, you have

```
$(".ProductPriceRating em span").text()
```

This could be the problem, because there also is a span with the class "Rating"